# Запрос в базу на получение записи по id

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, get

Помогите составить корректный запрос в базу что бы можно было получать каждую запись по id, как single page.

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('ERROR: missing ID.');

include_once 'DB/database.php';
include_once 'Objects/dvd.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$dvdList = [];
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM dvd WHERE id = ' ); 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$dvdList[$row['id']] = new Dvd($row);
}
foreach ($dvdList as $dvd) {
echo "<h3 class='product-title'>{$dvd->name}</h3>";
echo "<p class='product-description'>{$dvd->description}</p>";
echo "<h6 class='price'>Price: {$dvd->price}<i class='glyphicon-euro'></i></h6>";
echo "<h6 class='sizes'>Capacity: {$dvd->capacity} mb </h6>";
}
```

Если писать после `id =` просто цифру то запись получается из базу, как корректно составить что бы получать по id

До этого в классе Objects/dvd.php был метод 
     ` function readOne(){

```
    $query = "SELECT scu, name, img, price, description, capacity FROM dvd
        WHERE id = ? LIMIT 0,1";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //data that will be executed in `dvd_id`
    $this->scu = $row['scu'];
    $this->name = $row['name'];
    $this->img = $row['img'];
    $this->description = $row['description'];
    $this->price = $row['price'];
    $this->capacity = $row['capacity'];
}
```

Так получил запись по ключу, сейчас переделываю проект больше под ооп, создал абстрактный класс родителя Objects.product.php

```
abstract class Product
{
public $id;
public $scu;
public $img;
public $name;
public $price;
public $description;

public function __construct($data)
{
    // $data - это строка извлеченная из БД.
    // Соответственно индексы - это имена полей в таблице
    $this->id    = $data['id'];
    $this->img   = $data['img'];
    $this->scu   = $data['scu'];
    $this->name  = $data['name'];
    $this->price = $data['price'];
    $this->description = $data['description'];
}
```

}

Comment: "Если писать после id = просто цифру то запись получается из базу, как корректно составить что бы получать по id"  - что, простите?

Comment: да если просто написать `SELECT * FROM dvd WHERE id = 16` то получаю запись `http://localhost/TreeList/ProductList/dvd_id.php?id=16 ` запрос корректно отрабатывается данные все получаю

Comment: в процедурном стиле писал так  `$sql = SELECT * FROM dvd WHERE id = ".$dvd_id;`

Comment: То есть вы хотите взять динамичный `id` в запрос вместо прописанного руками 16? Так у вас в функции ` readOne()` вроде это и происходит, разве нет?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1.** Нет необходимости использовать **`LIMIT`** при запросе одной записи по **`id`** .

**2.** Проверьте, получаете ли вы значение **`id`** через **`$this->id`**.

**3.** Используйте такие варианты подстановки значений:

```
$query = "SELECT scu, name, img, price, description, capacity FROM dvd
    WHERE id = ?";
$stmt->bindParam("i", $this->id);

$query = "SELECT scu, name, img, price, description, capacity FROM dvd
    WHERE id = :id";
$sth->bindParam(":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

[PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

[PDO::PARAM_INT](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)